# Call an object once and assign different input parameters in different instances

Tags: java, object

In Java,

Suppose I have an object class called 'Module'
and another class called 'Student' accepts the input parameter of 'Module'
How can I create an object **once** but then just assign it different values every time (in the interest of efficiency and memory conservation)

Here is an example of my inefficient code where I create multiple objects

```
public class StudentTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Student s1 = new Student ("Joe", "Bloggs", 19, new Module("com1028", "come1028", 70, 120) );
Student s2 = new Student("Stella", "Kazamia", 24, new Module("com1026", "come1032", 40, 60) );
System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
    }

}
```

How can I create only 1 student, and only 1 module, but assign them different input parameters for the respective individuals.

Comment: Your code is hardly inefficient...
If there are multiple students, it makes sense to have multiple instances of the Student class. If you want to change the information for a student, then just update the variables inside of the Student instance.

Comment: *"How can I call an object once..."* You don't "call" objects. What do you mean? Create?

Comment: How much nanoseconds are you trying to save? :D

Comment: @explv while I understand where you're coming from, theoretically I could store the students in an array. Then I would only need to call one student object and select their name from the array each time i use the same object. But in this case, I want to see if there's an alternative to that

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes i mean create, are those two words not analogous to eachother?

Comment: *"How can I call only 1 student, and only 1 object, but assign them different input parameters for the respective individuals;"* It depends entirely on the implementation of `Student` (and possibly `Module`). Fundamentally: You set their properties to new values, usually via setters -- if they provide them.

Comment: @user36606: No, "call" and "create" are not analogous to each other. You *call* methods (functions, etc.). You *create* objects (amongst other things you do with them).

Comment: @NabinBhandari I appreciate that this is a very simple program, however I felt it illustrates exactly what I wish to achieve should I have been working on something of a larger scale

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for the clarification, I'll make the relevant edit

Comment: @T.J.Crowder indeed, both classes are essentially composed solely of getters, setters and their relative constructor class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I call only 1 student, and only 1 object, but assign them different input parameters for the respective individuals

It depends entirely on the implementation of `Student` (and possibly `Module`). Fundamentally: You set their properties to new values, usually via setters — if they provide them.

For instance, suppose `Student` looks like this:

```
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private Module module;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int age, Module module) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.module = new Module(module); // Defensive copy
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }
    // ...and so on for lastName and age...

    public void setModule(Module module) {
        this.module = new Module(module); // Defensive copy
    }
    public Module getModule() {
        return new Module(this.module); // Defensive copy
    }
}
```

Note the defensive copies, since you've said `Module` provides setters (so it wouldn't make sense for `Student` to use the instance you hand it).

In that case, you could avoid creating a second `Student`, like this:

```
Student s = new Student ("Joe", "Bloggs", 19, new Module("com1028", "come1028", 70, 120) );
System.out.println(s);
s.setFirstName("Stella");
s.setLastName("Kazamia");
s.setAge(24);
s.setModule(new Module("com1026", "come1032", 40, 60));
System.out.println(s);
```

...but you've still had to create a new `Module` to pass to the setter (and the setter creates a copy of it to keep).

If you want to avoid defensive copies, you'll want to make `Module` **immutable**, so that `Student` can happily keep the instance you pass it. You'd still need to create a new `Module` when updating the `s` instance, though.

**I'm not saying reusing the `s` instance is a good idea**. The JVM is really good at garbage collection, and is particularly good at optimizing it within a method when the references to objects created within that method don't survive method termination (where it matters; e.g., if the method is used a **lot**).

Instead, I would just do the straightforward thing (what you have in your question) and **if** that code turned out to be the source of a memory pressure issue, look at why that is *then*, when you have that information, and deal with it.

E.g.: Don't micro-optimize prematurely. :-)

Comment: would it be possible to initialise a module object in the student class. From there, make it accept the module parameters as part of the student object

Comment: @user36606: Sure, you could do that.

Comment: so each time i initialise a new student, would that create a new module object or just call the same one from within the student class

Comment: @user36606: As far as I know, the `Student` class has no module object. *Instances* do, but not the class.